# changing "setOrder" value removes price from product group data. Or price data not found for product groups

Tags: magento-1.9

The code looks something like this:

```
<?php 
$category_id = '1';
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
...
->setOrder('price', 'asc'); 
?>
...
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
...
<?php print_r($_products->getItems()); ?>
...
```

When doing print_r I get all the data relating to the product. If ordering by price as seen above I find the following fields amongst the data:

```
[price] => 
[tax_class_id] => 2
[final_price] => 0
[minimal_price] => 16.6250
[min_price] => 16.6250
[max_price] => 16.6250
[tier_price] =>
```

This is great. It allows me to show a "from: xxxx" price when listing product groups.

However if I order by something else such as

```
->setOrder('name', 'asc'); or 
->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc'); (added attribute)
```

then the price data is missing when doing print_r. It's just missing.

How do I sort the products in a category in another way than price, and still retain the price info for product groups?

Comment: All this is handled in the toolbar template. Why are you rolling your own? Anyway, the attributes you want to sort on, need to have that flag set in their properties. To retain price info, look into Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php and look for something like addPriceData().

Comment: Thanks Melvyn. I didn't manage to explain it properly. Basically we have an area showing "latest products" where we wish to order the products by date. To do this we rely on an attribute "news_from_date". What we noticed though is that whenever we order NOT based on price, the price info for items representing a group is missing. It does not say "From XXXX". However if we change the setOrder to use 'price', then the group item correctly include "From XXXX". All those fields I  highlighted with price, tax_class_id, finalprice, minimal price etc.

Answer (score 0):

This was the line printing the price:

```
< ?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

which to get the price to show for a product representing a group had to be replaced with a loop going through all of the grouped products to find the price to show (in our case the lowest price):

```
<?php 
if ($_product->isGrouped()) {
  $aProductIds = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
  $minprice = 99999999999999;
  $_finalPrice = '';

  foreach ($aProductIds as $ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
      $aProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
      if($minprice > $aProduct->getPriceModel()->getPrice($aProduct)) {
       $minprice = $aProduct->getPriceModel()->getPrice($aProduct);
       $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($aProduct, $aProduct->getFinalPrice());
      }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="price-box">
      <p class="minimal-price">
       <span class="price-label">From:</span>
       <span class="price"><?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_finalPrice, $includingTax = true), true, false);?>< /span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
else {
  echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this an addition to the question or an answer? You should either edit you question instead, or mark your own anser as accepted